# Verify if a string variable has two decimal numbers

Tags: javascript, angular

The type of Myvar is string.
How to check if my var has two decimal numbers. like this `Myvar ='5.50'`

Comment: `Myvar.split(".")[1].length === 2`

Comment: @tymeJV `Myvar = "hel.lo"`?

Comment: It was just a comment to get the logic started - needs additional logic... like if there is no decimal, is it a number, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like

```js
const test = x => !isNaN(+x) && Boolean(x.match(/\...$/));

console.log(test('qwer'));
console.log(test('12'));
console.log(test('12.34'));
console.log(test('12.345'));
```

Comment: Thanks it's working

Answer (score 1):

Basically just split on the decimal point and check the length of the second parts

```
let decimalNumber = +Myvar; //use + to cast to number, will be NaN if not number
let hasDecimal = Myvar.contains(".");

if (!isNaN(decimalNumber) && hasDecimal) {
   let hasTwoDecimalPlaces = Myvar.split(".")[1].length === 2;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it's working

Answer (score 1):

Use a [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/RegExp/test): `/^\d+.\d{2}$/`

```js
console.log(/^\d+.\d{2}$/.test('5.50')); // true
console.log(/^\d+.\d{2}$/.test('5.5')); // false
console.log(/^\d+.\d{2}$/.test('5.5a')); // false
```

Comment: Thanks it's working

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myVar = '5.50';

if (Number(myVar))
    console.log(myVar.split('.')[1].length)

var myVar2 = 'rr.pr';

if (Number(myVar2))
    console.log(myVar.split('.')[1].length)
```

Comment: That does not confirm that the decimals are actually a number

Comment: Ok, made a check then

Comment: Thanks it's working